# Insertar un Joystick en un layout en android studio

Tags: java, android

Muy buenas, tengo una clase "joystick" que quiero proyectar en el layout de una clase "Juego" pero no consigo colocarla.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="657dp"
    android:background="@drawable/prado1">

    <com.matteo.progetto.Joystic
        android:id="@+id/Mando"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="555dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Ahora tengo el joystick manualmente centrado en el layout y del tamaño justo, todo hecho manualmente en la clase del joystick y proyectado en el layout "juego" en que pero obscura todo lo que hay detrás.

El layout game tiene una imagen de un prado que quiero haga de background al joystick y a todo lo que tendré que añadir, ahora recibo solo la proyección de la clase Joystick mientras el layout "game" y el cuadradito gris en que quiero insertar el joystick están obscurados.

Socorro y gracias.

Añado pantallazos del layout en el que querría proyectar el joystick:

[image: layout en el que querría proyectar el joystick]

y del resultado en el emulador, osea el joystick que obscura el layout de juego, mientras tendría que encajar en el box "joystic" del primero pantallazo;

[image: Joystick]

Esta es la clase del Joystick:

[image: Clase J1]

[image: ClaseJ2]

[image: ClaseJ3]

[image: Clase J4]